# UWP XAML x:Bind inherited interfaces are not recognized

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, xbind

When using x:Bind in a UWP XAML application consider the following:

```
interface IBaseInterface
{
    string A { get; set; }
}
interface ISubInterface : IBaseInterface
{
    string B { get; set; }
}
class ImplementationClass : ISubInterface
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

In the Page class we have the following:

```
public partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ISubInterface TheObject = new ImplementationClass { A = "1", B = "2" };
    //All the rest goes here
}
```

In the MainPage XAML we have the following snippet:

```
<TextBlock Text={x:Bind Path=TheObject.A}></TextBlock>
```

Which causes the following compiler error:
XamlCompiler error WMC1110: Invalid binding path 'A' : Property 'A' can't be found on type 'ISubInterface'

The following does work however:

```
<TextBlock Text={x:Bind Path=TheObject.B}></TextBlock>
```

Does anybody know if it is a known limitation of the UWP XAML platform that inherited interface-properties are not recognized by the compiler?
Or should this be considered a bug?
Are there any known workarounds?

Help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try to define `TheObject` as `IBaseInterface` rather than `ISubInterface` and see if the Compiler then accepts `TheObject.A`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, after doing some test and reseach, it seems that inherited interface-properties are not recognized by the compiler when using the X:Bind.

As a workaround we can use the traditional Binding instead of the X:Bind as following:

In the .xaml:

```
<Grid Name="MyRootGrid">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

In the xaml.cs:

```
MyGrid.DataContext = TheObject;
```

Comment: Thanks for trying and coming to the same conclusion as I did. I did submit a bug via Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1770944

Answer (score 1):

If you write a class Foo inherited IFoo.

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged, IF1
{
    public Foo(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    private string _name;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    string IF1.Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

}

public interface IF1
{
    string Name { set; get; }
}
```

And when you write a list in page

```
  public ObservableCollection<Foo> Foo { set; get; } = new ObservableCollection<Foo>()
    {
        new Foo("jlong"){}
    };
```

How can you bind it in xaml?

I find a way to bind it. You should use `x:bind` and use `Path=(name:interface.xx)` to bind it in xaml.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Foo}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Foo">
                <TextBlock Text="x:Bind Path=(local:IFoo.Name)"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the namespace of the base class via a xmlns at the top of the file:

```
xmlns:base="using:Namespace.Of.Base.Class"
```